# TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to run the detect_ts function from pyculiarity package but getting this error on passing a two-dimensional dataframe in python.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from pyculiarity import detect_ts
>>> data=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\nikhil.chauhan\\Desktop\\Bosch_Frame\\dataset1.csv',usecols=['time','value'])
>>> data.head()
   time  value
0     0   32.0
1   250   40.5
2   500   40.5
3   750   34.5
4  1000   34.5
>>> results = detect_ts(data,max_anoms=0.05,alpha=0.001,direction = 'both')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Windows\System32\pyculiar-0.0.5\pyculiarity\detect_ts.py", line 177, in detect_ts
    verbose=verbose)
  File "C:\Windows\System32\pyculiar-0.0.5\pyculiarity\detect_anoms.py", line 69, in detect_anoms
    decomp = stl(data.value, np=num_obs_per_period)
  File "C:\Windows\System32\pyculiar-0.0.5\pyculiarity\stl.py", line 35, in stl
    res = sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(data.values, model='additive', freq=np)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\seasonal.py", line 88, in seasonal_decompose
    trend = convolution_filter(x, filt)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\filters\filtertools.py", line 303, in convolution_filter
    result = _pad_nans(result, trim_head, trim_tail)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\filters\filtertools.py", line 28, in _pad_nans
    return np.r_[[np.nan] * head, x, [np.nan] * tail]
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: I'd review the docs for `detect_ts`.  Make sure the inputs are the right type(s).  `data.values` extracts an array from `data`.  The other approach is to work from the end, deducing what `head`, `x`, and `tail` are.  `[np.nan]*np.float64(2)` produces your error.

Comment: The same error occured to me... When I enabled the folder path for accessing the data. (For eg: G folder/Shared link)
The error got rectified because link to access data was activated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code might be that `np.nan` is a `float64` type value but the `np.r_[]` **expects** comma separated **integers** within its square brackets.
Hence you need to convert them to **integer** type first.

But we have another problem here.

```
return np.r_[[(int)(np.nan)] * head, x, [(int)(np.nan)] * tail]
```

This should have solved the problem in ordinary cases....
But it wont work in this case, as **NaN cannot be type casted to integer type.**

```
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Thus, no proper solution can be suggested unless we know what you are trying to do here. Try providing a bit more details about your code and you are sure to get help from us.

**:-)**